# Use stored passwords in Firefox, but stop asking for more?

Tags: firefox, passwords, login

I have only a couple sites for which I want Firefox to hold the passwords and auto-fill when I visit.  However, I do not want to be asked about storing ANY other passwords.  If I turn off the option to **ask** about storing passwords, it also turns off the ability to use the already stored ones.

The option in settings doesn't say "Don't use stored passwords". It says "**Ask** to save logins and passwords for websites". *Saving and using are independent actions.*

Is there a middle ground where Firefox will use what it has, but not ask to add more?

Alternatively, is there a way to use a wild-card to cover most/all sites in the "exceptions" list of sites Firefox won't ask to store passwords?  E.G. if I could tell FF to not ask for `https://*.com` that would give me a decent workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: You might try setting key4.db and logins.json in your profile to read-only (N.B. I've not tested this, but theoretically, it should prevent any changes, though you might get dialog to add password). See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Comment: If it's anywhere, there might be an option in the advanced configuration config file. The place to ask is forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=38 .

Comment: I've been wanting to do the same thing, use existing saved passwords in Firefox Lockwise but do not ask to save new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`userChrome.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css), you can disable the password panel that pops up asking if you want to save the password. I inspected the element and it's a panel with attribute `popupid` where the value is `password`.

```
panel[popupid="password"]
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

If you also want to disable the password key icon that shows up in the address bar, you can do the same for that. Its id is `#password-notification-icon`.

```
#password-notification-icon
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Great solution!  I opened a bug with Mozilla because the asking and the using should be independent.  However, your suggestion is a good workaround.  I can use the passwords I have stored (and store more as I want), but don't get harassed every time I log into a new site.  Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the element was changed from <panel> to <popupnotification>:
popupnotification[popupid="password"]
{
  display: none !important;
}